# Enlarge interactive map - specifically an svg

Tags: dictionary, svg

I've used this tutorial - http://www.netzgesta.de/mapper/ to create an interactive map (http://teamworksdesign.com/clients/neurosign/contact/alabama/), the problem is I want to enlarge it by 10-20% to fill the space a bit better.

I've used these two images:

[image]

And the svg:

http://teamworksdesign.com/clients/neurosign/wp-content/themes/default/images/usa_map.svg

Obviously the png is easy enough to enlarge in PS but how can I enlarge the svg whilst keeping all it's coordinates in place?

UPDATE:
Changing this line below on the svg doesn't affect the size of the svg, the hover states just stay the same original size:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 432 275">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SVG is a vector-format. So if you just change the width and height-attributes on the root-element to 100% each and leave the viewport on the original pixel-values, it will fill the available space while every coordinate is re-calculated by the parser. The sized of the displayed picture now depends on where it is embedded.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 432 275">
```

Also, instead using JavaScript for hover-effects, I would use CSS (e.g. `polygon:hover { fill: #32cd32; }`).

Comment: Cheers. I opened the svg in Illustrator and just dragged it to the correct size. Uploaded that but when I tried the page the coordinates were still mapped out to the old size.

Comment: I don't know about Illustrator or what you mean with "dragged it to the correct size". You don't need to give a specific size to an SVG. Please make sure, you understood the [difference between vector (e.g. SVG, AI) and bitmap (e.g. PNG, JPEG) graphics](http://www.tutorialsroom.com/tutorials/graphics/bitmapvsvector.html). I've just changed the width and height in Chromiums Inspector, a text-editor would work as well…

Comment: Ok I've tried editing the svg in textedit and changed the line - '<svg width="432px" height="275px" viewBox="0 0 432 275" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">' to '<svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 432 275" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">' but the hover states are still the original size.

Comment: "the hover states are still the original size" I can't reproduce that in any browser.

Comment: Any chance you could take a screenshot of what your changing, it would be a great help. I think something maybe over-riding it because when I make the change you suggested the map doesn't get any bigger.

Comment: https://static.thomas-heuer.eu/snippets/usa_map_100pc.svg It will be displayed at the size, specified in the `viewport` when displaying with e.g. [eog](http://projects.gnome.org/eog/) or [Inkscape](http://www.inkscape.org/), but it will stretch to the full width available, when displayed in a browser (as a single file or embedded [e.g. using `<embed>` or `<iframe>`]).

Comment: ok, when viewing the actual svg file on my hosting it stretches the full width etc. I still can't get it to do that when viewing the actual page, it's still the same size. I've tried making all the elements above it bigger so the 100% fills that space but it just doesn't expand.

Answer (score 0):

Change the width and height in pixels, but keep the viewBox as it is. For example, to double to size:

```
<svg width="832px" height="550px" viewBox="0 0 432 275" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
```

Comment: Thanks, I've also tried that, it seems like something is over-riding it.